# How to install this file with Python?

Tags: software-installation, python

I want to install this file: [cvxopt](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/download.php) in my Ubuntu 13.04. But I got the following error message:

```
running install
running build 
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'base' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c C/base.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/C/base.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c C/dense.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/C/dense.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c C/sparse.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/C/sparse.o
C/sparse.c: In function ‘sparse_concat’:
C/sparse.c:368:28: warning: variable ‘blk_ncols’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/C/base.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/C/dense.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/C/sparse.o -lm -llapack -lblas -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cvxopt/base.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: This is not probably the full error message, or is it? Didn't you get also something like "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxxx"?

Comment: @volferine Yeah, you are right. I correct the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you don't have `lapack` and `blas` libraries. You should be able to install them like

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
```

When I tried the compilation it ended the same as for you, after installing the two libraries it finished successfully.

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working for me was installing `libncurses-dev`

```
sudo apt-get -y install libncurses-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `gcc` to do that. It resides in a package with the same name.

Comment: Thanks! But gcc is already installed on my computer. Could you kindly explain further what should I do?

Comment: @EdenHarder: go one step further and install the `build-essential` package. It contains the most used tools for compiling.